# how to script out proxy accounts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, scripting, proxy

I have servers where I use [proxy accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/122850/22336) to run ETL processes or even to [backup SSAS databases using powershell through a job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83088/22336).

I can see what AD Accounts are [related to my proxies](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111051/22336):

```
use msdb
go

select 
    s.job_id
    ,s.name as [job_name]
    ,js.step_id
    ,js.step_name   
    ,js.subsystem
    ,js.proxy_id
    ,js.command
    , c.credential_identity
from sysjobs S
INNER JOIN sysjobsteps JS ON S.job_id = js.job_id
INNER JOIN sysproxies p ON js.proxy_id = p.proxy_id
INNER JOIN sys.credentials as c on c.credential_id = p.credential_id
```

[image]

I can script out [roles](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/113156/22336) and [logins](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218273/22336) and even [table types](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252128/22336) but now I need to script out my proxies.

**QUESTION:**
How to script out proxies?

I Want to script out the following:

[image]

I have got this so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#tmp_sp_help_proxy','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #tmp_sp_help_proxy

create table #tmp_sp_help_proxy(proxy_id int null, 
                               name nvarchar(128) null, 
                               credential_identity nvarchar(128) null, 
                               enabled tinyint null, 
                               description nvarchar(1024) null, 
                               user_sid varbinary(40) null,  
                               credential_id int null, 
                               credential_identity_exists int null)

insert into #tmp_sp_help_proxy(proxy_id, name, credential_identity, enabled, description, user_sid, credential_id, credential_identity_exists) 
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_proxy



SELECT
tshp.name AS [Name],
tshp.proxy_id AS [ID],
CAST(tshp.enabled AS bit) AS [IsEnabled],
ISNULL(tshp.description,N'''') AS [Description],
tshp.credential_id AS [CredentialID],
ISNULL(sc.name,N'''') AS [CredentialName],
ISNULL(tshp.credential_identity,N'''') AS [CredentialIdentity]
FROM
#tmp_sp_help_proxy AS tshp
INNER JOIN sys.credentials AS sc ON sc.credential_id = tshp.credential_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBATools has a convenient command [`Copy-DbaAgentProxy`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaAgentProxy) in its PoSh module that I highly recommend.

> By default, all proxy accounts are copied. The -ProxyAccounts parameter is auto-populated for command-line completion and can be used to copy only specific proxy accounts.
>
> If the associated credential for the account does not exist on the destination, it will be skipped. If the proxy account already exists on the destination, it will be skipped unless -Force is used.

Or, to generate the files, you can also use [`Get-DbaAgentProxy`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaAgentProxy) and [`Export-DbaScript`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Export-DbaScript).